# Using cheap unlimited hosting as ftp backup location?

Tags: ftp, hosting

I was looking for the best/cheapest FTP storage to store my server backups on, and I came across several very cheap unlimited hosting plans including ftp and ssh access.

I'm talking about shared website hosting plans for less than $10/month with unlimited disk space and network volume. As these plans include ftp, I could technically use it as a backup location. I would only use it as a plan B (my main backup plan is using a more reliable location), but it would accumulate to at least 1TB of data rather quickly.

It looks like too good to be true, to have unlimited storage for < $10/month. So what's the catch? I don't see anything on the website telling me this use case is not allowed, but I haven't read through all legal documents...  Of course I could set up a small website on that hosting, just so it's really used to host a website (and also a lot of backups).

Comment: The catch is that they will tell you to bugger off faster than you can upload once it is clear what you try to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The catch is that they will tell you to bugger off faster than you can upload once it is clear what you try to do.

They may even hit you with a large invoice if they have a fair use or similar clause and explicitly forbit storage of non-serving content.